# Checkbox List Checked Value Lost after page refresh

Tags: reactjs

How do I bring back my checkbox list checked values in react after navigating away the page and then coming back? I read some suggestions to use localstorage and I can save the checked value to a localstorage variable. Then to display the localstorage variable?  My checkbox code is as below

```
handleCampusChkChange = (id, name, value, checked) => {
  const checkedCampusItems = this.state.checkedCampusItems;
  console.log('campuschk=' + checkedCampusItems);
  let index;
  // check if the check box is checked or unchecked
  if (checked) {
    checkedCampusItems.push(value);
  } else {
    // or remove the value from the unchecked checkbox from the array
    index = checkedCampusItems.indexOf(value);
    checkedCampusItems.splice(index, 1);
  }

  this.setState({ checkedCampusItems: checkedCampusItems });
  this.updateURL();
  //save checked value in local storage
  localStorage.setItem('checkedCampusItems', checkedCampusItems);
}

render() {
  return (
    <CampusChk
      key={item.id}
      {...item}
      onChange={event =>
        this.handleCampusChkChange(
          item.id,
          item.name,
          item.value,
          event.target.checked
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing the checkbox state in `localStorage` then you have to read it when component is mounted

```
componentDidMount() {
    const stored = localStorage.getItem('checkedCampusItems');
    if (stored != null) {
        this.setState({ checkedCampusItems: stored.split(",")}); // I assume checkedCampusItems stored is a comma separated list
    }

}
```

Here is an example with functional components
https://codepen.io/LukaszGrela/pen/eYYOGRP

Comment: I tried and it does not work. The checkbox list lost checked value after page refresh. The checkedCampusItems state={
    
    checkedCampusItems:this.props.checkedCampusItems!==null?this.props.checkedCampusItems.split(','):[],
    
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can use localstorage to store / restore the component state, I attached an example demonstrating this:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/dazzling-lake-5bmd5

When you change the route, the component is destroyed, and it's state is lost, a solution to this is using localstorage, or you could store your state higher, maybe using 
[Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)